# Django -- Generate URL for the webpage of a database object

Tags: javascript, python, django, curl

I currently am working on a Django project that allows a user to upload a file (i.e. a .dat, .json, or .tar.gz), which then gets converted into the appropriate database objects with their various relations. The file can be uploaded either by using the interface on the web browser or via `curl` to the appropriate REST API endpoint. The site is currently a single-page sort of site that utilizes Bootstrap.js. The URL in the browser does not change whether the user is on the home page (which displays the most recent uploads) or clicks on one of the "blackboxes" uploaded ("blackbox" being the primary database object formed from the uploaded file). Clicking on a blackbox takes the user to a page of the list of "datapoints" that are inside the blackbox.

What I now need is for each blackbox page to have its own URL that can be returned in a response when a user or script uses `curl` to upload a blackbox. This is the pattern I was thinking of using in the URLconf:

```
r'^bb/(?P<bb_id>[0-9]+)/$'
```

where `bb` is short for "blackbox". How can I systematically make each blackbox page have its own URL following this pattern, when right now each blackbox page and the home page all have the same root URL (in development, `localhost:8000`)?

I have made some attempts (most likely very misguided) at something like this. One thing I tried was making a separate template for a blackbox page, using the `extends` template tag. The frontend Javascript has a function `display_points` that takes in a blackbox id and renders the list of datapoints, so I tried various hacky ways to call that function (which was in a file `home.html`) from within the blackbox page template, but nothing was successful. One thing that I hoped would work was using jQuery `$.getScript` for something like this:

```
$.getScript('blackboxes.js', function() { //blackboxes.js is the Javascript from home.html that I copied and pasted--hacky, I know
    display_points({{ bb_id }});
})
```

but I keep getting 404 errors from trying to use `$.getScript` like this despite trying different paths for the Javascript file.

Also, just in case this is an important detail for this question, the front end utilizes Clusterize.js to help load the datapoints, since the blackboxes usually have at least several thousand datapoints.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you put some code so that we can understand better the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is that a client side issue? That you don't know how to change URL in a single-page app? Or that you don't know how to handle on the server side when someone types URL in browser?

Comment: @freakish I think my issue is the former, that I don't know how to change URL in a single-page app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the key things to making something like this work was the use of the right template tags in our `home.html` which we renamed to `base.html` to be more descriptive of what the template is for. `urls.py` was also modified so that two different URL patterns would map to the same `base` view in `views.py`; the two patterns were a "blank" pattern (i.e. `r'^$'`) for the default home page and a pattern to view a particular blackbox (`r'^blackbox/(?P<bb_id>[0-9]+)/$'`). Different views would be rendered based on whether a `bb_id` (blackbox id) was in the URL pattern. If none, the default home view of the recent uploads would be rendered; otherwise, the datapoints of that particular `bb_id` would be rendered instead. In the `base.html` template, the `if` template tag was used to see if a `bb_id` existed; if so, the JavaScript function `display_bb` would be called, which takes in the `bb_id` to know which datapoints to display. Otherwise, the function `display_10_recent_blackboxes` would be called instead.

Another issue was sending a response that contained info that could be used to find and view the blackbox that was just uploaded. Originally, the main database insertion function `insertBlackboxIntoDatabase` would create the Blackbox model instance first and then fill it with datapoints created from the file uploaded. However, since the response is sent before that function is called, it was necessary to refactor the upload and insertion code such that the blackbox instance would be created first so that its ID could be part of the response. The ID would then be passed to the different upload functions (based on the filetype) that each end up calling `insertBlackboxIntoDatabase`, which now locates the Blackbox instance based on the ID passed to it and then proceeds to create and insert the datapoints.